# Website from scratch and security threats

Tags: security, web

Security threats on a website made **from scatch**.

What I have to do to protect my website?

Also what are other issues (apart from security) will show up during development, maintenance and managment of website.

Comment: Bugs, bugs, more bugs, ankward users, and late night's. Hope you like coffee

Answer (score 0):

Non-optimized scripts and loose development standards, are biggest threat to the security of a website. Using some good framework and following its architecture for developing a website from scratch can address it to a large extent. Following aspects of a website are among favorites of intruders to try getting unauthorized access to the website, and these should to be implemented with prudence to keep the website safe: -

~ User authentication
~ Server authentication
~ Validation of input & output data
~ Session & cookies management

Depending upon confidentiality of data on the website, use of SSL can add a further level of security to the website.

If you are going to follow Agile methodology then high level documentation of features & tools will save a lot of to-and-fro while development, and [thinking about the maintenance process & how to's](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/essentials-website-maintenance-considered-during-development-puri) will help developing efficient administration tools.